# Этимология слова "карапуз"

Tags: этимология

И я об этимологии. Интересует слово "карапуз". Оно имеет отношение к тюркскому языку (слышу тут "кара" — "черный") или мне просто показалось?
Спасибо

Comment: только возможно не к тюркскому, а к персидскому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По этимологическому словарю Крылова, этимология предлагает два варианта образования этого слова. Первый предполагает, что в исходном варианте это слово имело вид Коротопуз от коротый и пузо, а современное произношение и написание связано с развитием аканья. Согласно второму варианту, слово карапуз является заимствованием из тюркских языков, где значение слова карпуз ("арбуз") указывает на то, как шло переосмысление этого слова – "круглый и толстый, как арбуз

Comment: я бы проголосовал за персидское происхождение, славянское сокращение мне кажется странным и по типологии сокращения согласной и по смыслу слова (короткое пузо? ребенок инвалид?). тогда как персидкое (через тюркский) сохраняет основное представление - толстый малыш (арбуз). да и назвать малыша арбузом (арбузиком) мне кажется вполне можно и сейчас. по фонетике тоже вполне подойдет. карбуз - кар(а)пуз вместо пропадания бесследно смычной согласной в славянском варианте.